# Android emulator adb shell sqlite3: inaccessible or not found

Tags: android

I'm trying to inspect my app's database on an emulator using the procedure described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#sqlite). First command works just fine:

```
PS C:\some-dir\> adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell
generic_x86:/ $
```

The second one, though, is the problem:

```
127|generic_x86:/ $ sqlite3
/system/bin/sh: sqlite3: inaccessible or not found
```

Am I missing something here?

Here are my AVD details:

```
Name: Pixel_2_Android_Q
CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
Path: C:\some-dir\.android\avd\Pixel_2_Android_Q.avd
Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 29)
Skin: pixel_2
SD Card: 512M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: pixel_2
hw.lcd.width: 1080
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 29
tag.id: google_apis_playstore
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.camera.front: emulated
avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 2 Android Q
hw.gpu.mode: auto
hw.ramSize: 1536
PlayStore.enabled: true
fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
hw.cpu.ncore: 3
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.dPad: no
hw.lcd.height: 1920
vm.heapSize: 256
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: virtualscene
AvdId: Pixel_2_Android_Q
hw.lcd.density: 420
hw.arc: false
hw.device.hash2: MD5:55acbc835978f326788ed66a5cd4c9a7
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.battery: yes
hw.sdCard: yes
tag.display: Google Play
runtime.network.latency: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Same here, and not just the emulator, also my Galaxy S10e running Android 10. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142003176